# Predicate to unzip a list

Tags: list, prolog, tuples

```
List1=[(x,1),(y,1),(z,1)]
```

I'm attempting to split this list:

into two lists:

```
List3=[x,y,z]
List4=[1,1,1]
```

So I have written this predicate to try to do it:

```
splt([], [], []).
splt([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], [X,Y|Zs]) :-
    splt(Xs,Ys,Zs).
```

However instead of the desired result, the predicate returns:

```
1 ?- splt([(x,1),(y,2),(z,3)],L3,L4).
L3 = [_G1760, _G1769, _G1778],
L4 = [ (z, 1), _G1760, (y, 2), _G1769, (z, 3), _G1778].
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, the term you have chosen. This: `(a, b)`, is **most definitely not** how you would usually represent a "tuple" in Prolog. You almost always use `a-b` for a "pair", and pairs are used throughout the standard libraries.

So your initial list would look like this: `[x-1, y-1, z-1]`.

This should also explain why you are having your problem. You write `(a, b)`, but your predicate says `a, b`, and you consume two elements when you expect to get one `,(a,b)` term. So, to fix your current predicate you would write:

```
split([], [], []).
split([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], [(X,Y)|XYs]) :-
    split(Xs, Ys, XYs).

?- split(Xs, Ys, [(x,1), (y,1), (z,1)]).
Xs = [x, y, z],
Ys = [1, 1, 1].
```

But instead, using a more conventional name, term order, and Prolog pairs:

```
zip([], [], []).
zip([X-Y|XYs], [X|Xs], [Y|Ys]) :-
    zip(XYs, Xs, Ys).

?- zip([x-1, y-1, z-1], Xs, Ys).
Xs = [x, y, z],
Ys = [1, 1, 1].
```

And of course, SWI-Prolog at least has a [library(pairs)](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=pairs), and it comes with a `pairs_keys_values/3`:

```
?- pairs_keys_values([x-1, y-1, z-1], Xs, Ys).
Xs = [x, y, z],
Ys = [1, 1, 1].
```

Comment: Great answer! It is worth expanding a bit why `(a,b)` would be a bad choice to represent pairs: For example, one of the reasons is that `,` is already used for so many other things in Prolog: `','/2` for conjunctions, `,` in lists like `[a,b,c]`, and even to separate predicate arguments like in `p(A, B, C) :- ...`.

Comment: A downside of both `(',')/2` and `(-)/2`: They are both associative, whereas Haskell's `(a,b)` is not associative, you have to write `(a,(b,c))`

Comment: @false You mean that `(a,b,c)` end up as `','(a,','(b,c))` instead of `','(a,b,c)`, and `a-b-c` ends up as `-(-(a,b),c)`?

Comment: @Boris: yes. This ambiguity does not exist in Haskell. `(a,b,c)` and `(a,(b,c))` have nothing in common.

Comment: @false Well, I know it sounds apologetic, but I have always thought of `a-b` as a _pair_, not a tuple, and also my feeling about tuples is that if you are using them in practice as data structures you might as well give them names. What would be a good example where a nameless tuple of higher arity is needed?

Comment: Well, Haskell offers many of them. And the are rather called triples etc.

Comment: @false pair, triple, quadruple, quintuple, sextuple, septuple (?), octuple, argh .... My linguistic powers are deserting me!

Comment: [Here it is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple#Names_for_tuples_of_specific_lengths). And the meaning is thus: tuple for **any length** including 0 and 1. (I always thought that tuple comes from duplex, but I was wrong). And: Lenght=2 **is** also called a pair!

Comment: @false we totally need a prolog library for terms of all these lengths, with the appropriate names. Not joking, it sounds like a fun little project.

Answer (score 2):

You're matching the tuple as a whole, rather than it's component parts.

You should match on `[(X1,Y1)|XS]`, instead of `[X|XS]` and `[Y|Ys]`.

```
splt([],[],[]).
splt([(X1,Y1)|Xs],[X1|T1],[Y1|T2]):-
  splt(Xs,T1,T2).
```

Here the first term is used as input, the second and third as output.

Ideone example, using SWI-Prolog, [here](http://ideone.com/3VzJkr).

Comment: The problem is with the `[X,Y|Zs]`, which should be `[(X,Y)|Zs]` instead. Or am I wrong about this?

Comment: @Boris I could be wrong. But I think the first term is the one that's supposed to match the tuple. And I think the  `[X,Y|Zs]` is meant to be output.

Comment: @Boris I tested the tuple matching in ideone, selecting SWI-Prolog.

Comment: @Boris Updated my answer. To be honest, I was still working on the problem when _somebody_ ;-) posted a much better answer.

Comment: Sorry :( But now that I looked at the question more carefully: the predicate definition _almost_ gets to the point where it works, and it has the list with "tuples" as the last argument. Then, in the example, the list with the tuples is the first argument....

Comment: @Boris Nothing to be sorry about! This discussion gave me a good reason to improve the answer. And indeed, OP does seem to have a few conflicting thoughts. Probably a result of trying out different approaches.

Answer (score 2):

I find comfortable using library([yall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall)):

```
?- maplist([(X,Y),X,Y]>>true, [(x,1),(y,2),(z,3)],L3,L4).
L3 = [x, y, z],
L4 = [1, 2, 3].
```

or, maybe clearer

```
?- maplist([A,B,C]>>(A=(B,C)), [(x,1),(y,2),(z,3)],L3,L4).
L3 = [x, y, z],
L4 = [1, 2, 3].
```

Comment: I think the first version is much better, the second is an unnecessary indirection.