# Weird unification in Prolog

Tags: prolog, unification

I have the following program:

```
%% adjacent((Xs, Ys), (Xa, Ya)) - <Xa, Ya> is adjacent to <Xs, Ys>.
adjacent((Xs, Ys), (Right, Ys)) :- Right is Xs + 1.
adjacent((Xs, Ys), (Left, Ys)) :- Left is Xs - 1.
adjacent((Xs, Ys), (Xs, Up)) :- Up is Ys + 1.
adjacent((Xs, Ys), (Xs, Down)) :- Down is Ys - 1.
```

When I make

```
?- adjacent((5, 6), (X, Y)).
```

it gives me

```
X = Y, Y = 6 ;
X = 4,
Y = 6 ;
X = 5,
Y = 7 ;
X = Y, Y = 5.
```

What's happening?

Comment: Don't use "tuples", those are not what you think they are. `(a, b)` is actually `','(a, b)`, which is not so bad, but `(a,b,c)` is actually `','(a,','(b,c))`, in other words, a nested term instead of a flat term. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36932359/1812457) and the comments below it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I realize I am stupid. SWI-Prolog was simply aggregating the variables' values on the output when it was the same for both...